# Should I cast and normalize my discrete observation space for stable baselines 3 custom environments?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I read Antonin Raffin's [SB3 RL Tips and Tricks](https://araffin.github.io/slides/rlvs-tips-tricks/) and I am wondering if I should use a Box observation space and normalize or discrete observation space.

I have a toy problem where my observations are a sequence of 10 scores that have all lower bound 0 and upper bound from 10 to 200.
The variables values can be any integer from [0, upper bound].

Would you cast this to a continuous space and normalize or use discrete spaces?

I think discrete spaces might become computationally very expensive or is my intuition wrong here?

Thank you very much for your suggestions and insights!

Comment: You observation space **is** continuous, it is a multi-dimensional Box and I don't see a way you could cast it to a discrete space and I don't see any reason to do so. as for normalization, I personally almost always normalize observations in `[0, 1]` and actions in `[-1, 1]` if they are continuous. Gym has a [wrapper](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/wrappers/normalize.py#L49) for automatic handling of observations normalization

Comment: Thanks a lot for the confirmation @gehirndienst! I did feel like this is continuous and I used [-1, 1] right now. It works, but I wasn't sure if that is the right approach. I will try `[0, 1] as well. May I ask why you have `[0, 1]` and `[-1, 1]` in particular?

Comment: observations constitute an input layer of your [actor] neural network. Scaling values in it to `[0,1]` is a very standard practice in DL, which allows to experience faster convergence, less divergence etc. When you have continuous action space, you can't output a finite amount of Q-values or whatever value approximator from your network, you rather sample an action itself, while in 99% cases assuming that action distribution is Gaussian. Zero-centering scaling, i.e., having all variables within `[-1,1]` is also a common practice in statistics and ML resulting in faster learning.